# Why doesn't var = [0].extend(range(1,10)) work in python?

Tags: python, list

I would think that if i did the following code in python

```py
var = [0].extend(range(1,10))
```

then `var` would be a list with the values 0 - 9 in it.

What gives?

Comment: extend alters the list but returns nothing so var = None

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Oscar López and others have already explained, extend is a command, which returns None, to abide by command/query separation.

They've all suggested fixing this by using extend as a command, as intended. But there's an alternative: use a query instead:

```py
>>> var = [0] + range(1, 10)
```

It's important to understand the difference here. `extend` modifies your `[0]`, turning it into `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. But the `+` operator leaves your `[0]` alone, and returns a new list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

In cases where you've got other references to the list and want to change them all, obviously you need `extend`.

However, in cases where you're just using [0] as a value, using `+` not only allows you to write compact, fluid code (as you were trying to), it also avoids mutating values. This means the same code works if you're using immutable values (like tuples) instead of lists, but more importantly, it's critical to a style of functional programming that avoids side effects. (There are many reasons this style is useful, but one obvious one is that immutable objects and side-effect-free functions are inherently thread-safe.)

Answer (score 10):

[**`list.extend`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) is an in-place method. It performs its action on the object itself and returns `None`.

This would work:

```py
var = [0]
var.extend(range(1, 10))
```

Even better would be this:

```py
var = list(range(10))
```

Answer (score 6):

[extend()](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) doesn't return anything (actually `None`), it does the change "in-place", i.e., the list itself is modified.

I think you are after this:

```py
>>> var = [0]
>>> var.extend(range(1, 10))
>>> var
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: @nightcracker .. thanks for the edit -- don't like IPython much? ;-)

Comment: Never used or saw it, so I thought it was some made up syntax. So I edited into the more commonly known CPython format.

Comment: @nightcracker It's a really powerful (and awesome) Python shell worth looking into .. http://ipython.org/ .. I've been using it for a while, but keep discovering new features about it. I know others use it too since I see them paste their code too. (I do usually go back and take out the [] etc .. so thanks for doing that for me)

Answer (score 4):

For the code in the question to work, you'd need to do something like this:

```py
>>> var = [0]
>>> var.extend(range(1,10))
>>> var
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

It wasn't working before because [extend()](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) returns `None`, and that's by design: Python is abiding by [Command/Query Separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation).

Comment: +1 for teaching me about Command/Query Separation. I hadn't heard about that term before.